# Most efficient way to alter dataframe rows given a set condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know there are a couple ways to approach this but I wanted to implement the most efficient.

I need to add 1 or 2 to specific dataframe rows given a set condition. I have already created a mask of boolean values. The column adjusted will be predictions.

Code is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': preds_date,
                   'HE': HE_results,
                  'Predictions': y_pred})

#adjust model to capture peaks better
adjustHours = [6, 7, 15]
adjustHours_2 = [16, 17, 18, 19]

add1 = df['HE'].isin(adjustHours)
```

Essentially - I'm looking through hourly data and if boolean is True, then i want to adjust the predictions columns by 1 or 2 - dependent on if in 1st or 2nd array.

add1 here is a boolean mask of True and False, in this case True if the hour is 6,7, or 15.

Thanks!

Comment: Should be something like `df.loc[add1, 'Predictions'] += 1`. Similar for second list. Should also be pretty efficient but you should test it.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, create an `adjust_by_hour` map and then use `map` method on `HE` column to give corresponding adjusted hours:

```
adjust_by_hour = {6:1, 7:1, 15:1, 16:2, 17:2, 18:2, 19:2}
new_pred = df['Predictions'] + df['HE'].map(lambda x: adjust_by_hour.get(x, 0))
```

*Example*:

```
adjust_by_hour = {6:1, 7:1, 15:1, 16:2, 17:2, 18:2, 19:2}

he = pd.Series([6, 18, 3])
he   
#0     6
#1    18
#2     3
#dtype: int64

he.map(lambda x: adjust_by_hour.get(x, 0))
#0    1
#1    2
#2    0
#dtype: int64
```

Comment: Using "map" means to run a Python function for each row. This doesn't seem very efficient to me.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yeah, it depends on the size of data. You might get more performance out using `np.where` but as the condition is quite customized. The code can get quite verbose.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a number to the values in df['predictions'] where df['HE'] has a certain value?

You should probably use `where` or `mask`. They are basically the same function; where performs an operation where test_condition is false, mask performs where the test_condition is true.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': preds_date,
                   'HE': HE_results,
                  'Predictions': y_pred})

#adjust model to capture peaks better
adjustHours = [6, 7, 15]
adjustHours_2 = [16, 17, 18, 19]

## Here's the mask call, one easy line. 
df['Predictions'].mask(df['HE'].isin(adjustHours), df['Predictions'] += 1, inplace=True)
```

The basic syntax for mask is `pd.Series.mask(test_cond, other=nan, inplace=False)` There are some other kwargs too. `other=...` specifies what to replace the values in pd.Series with, such as pd.Series +1. mask is very fast as long as other is a vectorizable operation.